# FTP Server with MySQL access, and POST notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, sftp, rackspace-cloud

Im looking for an FTP server solution, that we can host either internally on a dedicated server, or on Rackspace Cloud/AWS, that provides a HTTP POST notification when a file is uploaded, and allows user accounts to be created either through an API or MySQL database.

There are several offerings that provide email notification - but has anyone come across anything that matches the above requirements.  BrickFTP being a IaaS system is an option, but we would prefer something hosted in house.

I don't believe the standard FTP servers provided with Apache can do the above ... can they?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [CrushFTP](http://www.crushftp.com). It can run on a number of platforms and is very reasonably priced. Support is great and it is very feature rich. There is a free trial available and support is good even during trial. Supports SFTP,FTPS and other protocols I belive SQL integration is supported but have not used this.

The system will send alerts based on a number of criteria like an upload(POST) or download. It has so many features you will likley need to test for some time to explore all options.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - i've spent the last 20 minutes reading the website and support docs and cannot find any suggestion of a POST on upload, but I agree its very well spec'd.  I've sent them an email, asking the question.